# DBSCAN returns partial clusters

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I am trying to implement the code for DBSCAN here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBSCAN

The portion I am confused about is

`expandCluster(P, NeighborPts, C, eps, MinPts)
   add P to cluster C
   for each point P' in NeighborPts 
      if P' is not visited
         mark P' as visited
         NeighborPts' = regionQuery(P', eps)
         if sizeof(NeighborPts') >= MinPts
            NeighborPts = NeighborPts joined with NeighborPts'
      if P' is not yet member of any cluster
         add P' to cluster C`

My code is below. As is, it currently returns partial clusters where a point should be density connected even if it is not in the immediate eps neighborhood. My code only returns the first few neighbors for each point.

```
import numpy 
import time 
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
import re, math


def haversine(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees) returned as kilometers 
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km



def ST_DBSCAN(points,max_distance,MinPts):
    global visited
    visited = []
    noise = []
    cluster_id = 0
    clusters = []
    in_cluster = []
    for p in points: 
        if p not in visited:
            # neighbor_points = []
            visited.append(p)
            NeighborPts = regionQuery(p,points,max_distance)
            if len(NeighborPts) < MinPts:
                noise.append(p)
            else:
                cluster_id = cluster_id + 1
                g = expandCluster(p,NeighborPts,max_distance,MinPts,in_cluster)
                clusters.append(g)
    return clusters

#return len(NeighborPts)

def expandCluster(p,NeighborPts,max_distance,MinPts,in_cluster):
    in_cluster.append(p[0])
    cluster = []
    cluster.append(p[0])
    for point in NeighborPts:
        if point not in visited:
            visited.append(point)
            new_neighbors = regionQuery(point,points,max_distance)
            if len(new_neighbors) >= MinPts: 
                new_neighbors.append(NeighborPts)
            if point[0] not in in_cluster:
                 in_cluster.append(point[0])
                 cluster.append(point[0])             
    return  cluster




def regionQuery(p,points,max_distance):
    neighbor_points = []
    for j in points:
        if j != p:
           # print 'P is %s and j is %s' % (p[0],j[0])
            dist = haversine(p[1],p[2],j[1],j[2])
            if dist <= max_distance:
                neighbor_points.append(j)
    neighbor_points.append(p) 
    return neighbor_points
```

I have a subset below. Points 1 and 5 should be 10.76 km apart so they shouldn't be in the initial query but they should be included in the same cluster because point 5 is density connected through point 3.

```
pointList = [[1,36.4686,2.8289], 
[2,36.4706,2.8589], 
[3,36.4726,2.8889],
[4,36.4746,2.9189],
[5,36.4766,2.9489], 
[6,36.4786,2.9789],
[7,36.4806,3.0089], 
[8,36.4826,3.0389], 
[9,36.4846,3.0689], 
[10,36.4866,3.0989]]

points= pointList

g = ST_DBSCAN(points,10,3)
```

Comment: this doesn't answer your question, but if all you want is a working DBSCAN implementation, scikit-learn has a pretty good one

Comment: @oxymor0n Thanks for the comment. I am trying to implement my own function to improve my understanding of how it works and to give some flexibility in the distance calls (eventually, I want to add more dimensions).

Comment: I think the scikit version is not very good *if* you want to modify the distance function. It is too optimized for Euclidean distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `expandCluster` function forgets the new neighbors.

Your set update is swapped.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix the error by switching the set update by pop() off each point in new_neighbors and appending them to NeighborPts.